About "the root of all evil" from Mahabharata
In this experct from Mahabharata, the Nagas mentioned the root of evil:-

Approaching the king, let us bite him, so that our object will be accomplished. By his death the root of all evil will be torn up. This is the final deliberation of us all, O you who hearest with your eyes! Then, do speedily what you deemest proper.

But, What is "the root of all evil"? Did any other scriptures mentions it or is it just a description for their freedom from Janamejaya's Yagna?
